# Lex: recognizing data type in a file

Tags: c, lex

I'm a beginner in lex. My program is to read a file and recognize the data types.
I'm getting this error by writing "gcc -c lex.yy.c" in windows command line:-

**code1.l: In function 'yylex':**

**code1.l:8:2: error: expected ';' before '{' token**

My input file is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;
    long int c;
    long long int d;

    return 0;
}
```

My lex code is

```
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
%}

%%
    "int"
    {
        printf("%s ->Intger data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "float"
    {
        printf("%s ->Floating point data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "double"
    {
        printf("%s ->double data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "char"
    {
        printf("%s ->character data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "void"
    {
        printf("%s ->void data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "bool"
    {
        printf("%s ->boolean data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "long"([ ])([ ])* "int"
    {
        printf("%s ->long int data type\n", yytext);
    }
    "long"([ ])([ ])* "long"([ ])([ ])* "int"
    {
        printf("%s ->long long int data type\n", yytext);
    }
    ([a-z])* 
    {
        printf("%s ->Not a data type\n", yytext);
    }
    ([0-9])* 
    {
        printf("%s ->Not a data type\n", yytext);
    }

%%

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("sampleIO.txt","r");
    yyin=fp;
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't find the error.Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lex/flex`, the patterns must start right at the beginning of a line, as explained in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html):

> The rules section of the flex input contains a series of rules of the form:
>
>       `pattern   action`
> where the pattern must be unindented and the action must begin on the same line.

Moreover,

> Any indented text… is copied verbatim to the output.

So your indented patterns, starting at line 8 as indicated in the gcc error message, were just passed straight through to the `lex.yy.c` file, where they failed to compile because they are not valid C.

Also, patterns cannot have unquoted whitespace. So even with correct indentation, the pattern:

```
"long"([ ])([ ])* "int"
```

would need to be written

```
"long"([ ])([ ])*"int"
```

With the extra space, it looks to flex like a pattern (`"long"([ ])([ ])*`) and an action (`"int"`). There is no need to place parentheses around square brackets; that only serves to obscure the pattern. And flex includes both the `*` regular expression operator (0 or more repeats) and the `+` operator (1 or more repeats), so that pattern could be written as:

```
"long"[ ]+"int"
```

which is much clearer, but not actually correct; the words `long` and `int` could be separated by tabs or newline characters (or, as it happens, comments, but we won't get into that just yet). So a better but still not perfect pattern might be:

```
"long"[[:space:]]+"int"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it up for you. It compiles OK now. 
Update my source for white-space correctness.

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
"int"       { printf("%s ->Intger data type\n", yytext);             }
"float"     { printf("%s ->Floating point data type\n", yytext);     }
"double"    { printf("%s ->double data type\n", yytext);             }
"char"      { printf("%s ->character data type\n", yytext);          }
"void"      { printf("%s ->void data type\n", yytext);               }
"bool"      { printf("%s ->boolean data type\n", yytext);       }
"long"[[:space:]]+"int"                    { printf("%s ->long int data type\n", yytext);    }
"long"[[:space:]]+"long"[[:space:]]+"int"  { printf("%s ->long long int data type\n", yytext); }
.           { printf("%s ->Not a data type\n", yytext);         } // I would omit printf here..


%%
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("sampleIO.txt","r");
    yyin=fp;
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would you please explain what was my mistakes?

Comment: I do belive, it was  "long"([ ])([ ])* "long"([ ])([ ])* "int" and "long"([ ])([ ])* "int" that killed the magic. and thus translated inappropriately into C code. Flex generates a very useful C code, using #line directive, that enables you to pinpoint where in the LEX code did things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks...is there any way my indenting caused any problem? I see you indented very nicely.

Comment: Well I was always thought to indent that way. Strangely, I never asked why.

Comment: @CandyMan: Flex does, as you say, insert `#line` directives, which is why the error message as reported in the OP indicates that the error is on line 8 of the flex input, `"int"`. Also, `"long int"` does not match the same input as `"long"[ ][ ]*"int"`.

Comment: @rici I am aware of that, although I was not completely sure what he meant with those [][] --> any amount of empty spaces did not come to mind. (shame on me!)